# Blob counter using blob_dog

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to count the number of cubes in a picture.

Currently, the picture looks like this

[image: pic] (In the future, there will be actual stickers on the cube)

So far what I've done was to process the image so that you can only see the stickers

[image: stickers]

and use [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_blob.html) to group the blobs together. So far what iv seen is that the DoG approach is the best.

Now my question is, *how do I count the number of blobs* using the DoG approach?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2

from math import sqrt
from skimage import data
from skimage.feature import blob_dog, blob_log, blob_doh
from skimage.color import rgb2hsv, hsv2rgb,rgb2gray
from skimage.io import imshow, imread

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image_input = imread('testerbutred.png')

red_filtered = (image_input[:,:,0] > 150) & (image_input[:,:,1] < 100) & (image_input[:,:,2] < 110)
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
image_output = image_input.copy()
image_output[:, :, 0] = image_output[:, :, 0] * red_filtered
image_output[:, :, 1] = image_output[:, :, 1] * red_filtered
image_output[:, :, 2] = image_output[:, :, 2] * red_filtered


image = image_output
image_gray = rgb2gray(image)
blobs_log = blob_log(image_gray, max_sigma=30, num_sigma=10, threshold=.1)

# Compute radii in the 3rd column.
blobs_log[:, 2] = blobs_log[:, 2] * sqrt(2)

blobs_dog = blob_dog(image_gray, max_sigma=30, threshold=.1)
blobs_dog[:, 2] = blobs_dog[:, 2] * sqrt(2)

blobs_doh = blob_doh(image_gray, max_sigma=30, threshold=.01)

blobs_list = [blobs_log, blobs_dog, blobs_doh]
colors = ['yellow', 'lime', 'red']
titles = ['Laplacian of Gaussian', 'Difference of Gaussian',
          'Determinant of Hessian']
sequence = zip(blobs_list, colors, titles)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(9, 3), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax = axes.ravel()

for idx, (blobs, color, title) in enumerate(sequence):
    ax[idx].set_title(title)
    ax[idx].imshow(image)
    for blob in blobs:
        y, x, r = blob
        c = plt.Circle((x, y), r, color=color, linewidth=2, fill=False)
        ax[idx].add_patch(c)
    ax[idx].set_axis_off()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I can't understand why you use a DoG filter when you have so clean blobs.

Comment: "group the blobs together": what do you mean ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Im really new to this. Am i able to count the blobs without using the filter?

Comment: The standard tool is connected components detection, assuming you binarized the image.

Answer (score 0):

After following [Yves Daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196549/yves-daoust)'s advice, I got it to work without using DoG filter.

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imshow, imread
import cv2

#Get image input
image_input = imread('testerbutred.png')


#If not red pixel, set to black
red_filtered = (image_input[:,:,0] > 150) & (image_input[:,:,1] < 100) & (image_input[:,:,2] < 110)
image_filtered = image_input.copy()
image_filtered[:, :, 0] = image_filtered[:, :, 0] * red_filtered
image_filtered[:, :, 1] = image_filtered[:, :, 1] * red_filtered
image_filtered[:, :, 2] = image_filtered[:, :, 2] * red_filtered

#change red pixels to white
image_filtered[np.where((image_filtered==[255,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = [255, 255, 255]

#blob counting
image = image_filtered
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=5)

cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

blobs = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (36,255,12), -1)
    if area > 13000:
        blobs += 2
    else:
        blobs += 1

print('blobs:', blobs)


cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```